# Opening and closing subsets of topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a topological space. S subset of X, define T(S) as the closure of the interior of S. Define $T^n$ as the composition n times. For which n, if it exists, does $T^n$ stabilize (i.e. $T^m=T^{m+1}$ for all m>n)?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be $n=1$? $T(T(S))$ would just be the closure of the interior of $S$'s closed interior, so it would just be $T(S)$.

Comment: We also have $U(U(S))=U(S)$ where $U(S)=Int (Cl (S)).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c$ denote the closure operator and $i$ the interior; then
$$
T^2(S)=cici(S)
$$
Since $ici(S)\subseteq ci(S)$, we have $cici(S)\subseteq ci(S)$.

Let $U=i(S)$. Since $U$ is open and contained in $c(U)$, we have $U\subseteq ic(U)$, so $c(U)\subseteq cic(U)$.

> For instance, if $S=\{0\}\cup[1,2]$ (in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology), then $i(S)=(1,2)$ and $T(S)=[1,2]\ne S$. Therefore $n=2$ is the minimum so that, on every topological space, $T^n=T^{n+1}$.

Comment: So $n=2$. There are examples that show $n \neq 1$